# Conditional insert in SQL for an order system

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a question regarding a conditional insert.

[image: The Problem]

I want to be able to add the same ID in the ("tafelID" = tableID) column, ONLY if the ("betaalstatus" = pay status) is equal to true. What query do i have to use ?

I'm new to SQL. my query is below.

```
INSERT INTO Rekening (tafelID, betaalstatus) Select ('7', 'False')
WHERE not exists ( select 'False' )
```

Comment: INSERT has no WHERE clause.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Are you asking how to `INSERT` these values, or how to stop the table having more than one row for a single value of `tafelID` when `betallstatus` has a value of `'True'`?

Comment: @gillianfowler . . . I would suggest that you delete this question and ask a new question.  Be very clear on the logic you want to implement and provide sample data and desired results that illustrate what you want to do.

Comment: How to insert the value only if the "betaalstatus"  is true, this is for a windows form, I have an other query if the table doesn't have a bill

Comment: Your problem will likely need to be addressed in your application. And perhaps now is a good time to step back and really think about your GUI and how you guide the user in entering valid data and providing effective feedback to the user. When you present a list to the user for editing, your app code must execute the sql statements based on what the user has entered - a tsql statement cannot do that directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace "<...>" with the data in the nested select statement in FROM clause. you can use nested Case When statement for complex conditions.

```
INSERT INTO Rekening (tafelID, betaalstatus) 
Select Case WHEN betaalstatus = true THEN  tableID ELSE tafelID END tafelID, betaalstatus
FROM (SELECT <betaalstatus> AS betaalstatus, <tableID> AS tableID, <tafelID> AS tafelID)
-- i.e. (SELECT true AS betaalstatus, 7 AS tableID, 8 AS tafelID)
```